# How to remove html tags (span) wrap only with specific class name and without inner content from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want to remove few unwanted tags from the string to store the clean string into database.

I have tried to relate the string with regex expression.
This is what I have tried -- https://codepen.io/rushijagani/pen/wZxWRj

```
var data = '<p><span class="unwanted-span-one" data-hello="unwated-attr">Donec</span> rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. <span>Mauris</span> blandit aliquet elit, eget <span class="unwanted-span-two" data-hello="unwated-attr-two"> malesuada</span>.</p>'
```

I want to remove all span tag which has a class name start with "unwanted-span-", it should remove only the tag wrap not inside content.

so the desired output should be as follow

```
var data = '<p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. <span>Mauris</span> blandit aliquet elit, eget malesuada.</p>'
```

***Please note*** -- *we only need to remove span tags with class name starts "unwanted-span-" other span should remain as it is.*

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
var allData = $('*[class^="unwanted-span-"]').contents().unwrap();
console.log($(".all").html())
```

If you don't want to change HTML, you can try this:

```
var match = $('*[class^="unwanted-span-"]').get(0);
var test = $('p').html().replace(match.outerHTML,match.innerHTML);
console.log( test );
```

Of course if you have more than one match, you have to iterate on all matches :)

Comment: As I mention in the title It's a STRING not a DOM. So probably this works for the DOM only.

Comment: `var data = '<p><span class="unwanted-span-one" data-hello="unwated-attr">Donec</span> rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. <span>Mauris</span> blandit aliquet elit, eget <span class="unwanted-span-two" data-hello="unwated-attr-two"> malesuada</span>.</p>'`

I want above string to be converted in to this --- `var data = '<p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. <span>Mauris</span> blandit aliquet elit, eget malesuada.</p>'`

Comment: Remove span wrap which has 'unwanted-span-' class name but inner content remain as it is.

Comment: I have not mention DOM anywhere in the question. please see the title I have clearly mention STRING. and i need to handle this using jQuery so mention had to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use starts with operator like this:

```
var allData = $('.all').find("span[class^='unwanted-span']").css('color','blue');
```

I edit your codepen container https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwyayP

To remove use this:

```
var allData = $('.all').find("span[class^='unwanted-span']").remove();
```

To unwrap span text use this:

```
var allData = $('.all').find('span[class^="unwanted-span-"]').contents().unwrap();

console.log($('.all').html());
```

Comment: Thanks you for looking into it but I need to remove those span. Please see the desired output from the description.

Comment: Its simple, change css('color', 'blue') to remove(). var allData = $('.all').find("span[class^='unwanted-span']").remove();

Comment: Yes I have tried that one as well. But remove() will remove the entire markup and it's content also. I want to remove just <span....> and </span> not inside content of span. span's content should not be removed.

Comment: Ok, you can use simpe this ```var allData = $('p').text()
console.log('<p>'+allData+'</p>');``` check Your code pen.

Comment: ```var allData = $('.all').find('span[class^="unwanted-span-"]').contents().unwrap();
console.log($('.all').html());```